# Using nginx with reverse proxy in docker container not working

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, docker, docker-compose

I want everything starting with `/api` to be directed to `http://localhost:3007`

This is my nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes  1;

daemon off;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /usr/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3007;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
    include servers/*;
}
```

It works when I run it locally on my mac. But it's not working when I run it in a docker-container.

This is my docker-file:

```
FROM smebberson/alpine-nginx:latest
COPY /dist /usr/html/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "80:80"
```

The error I'm getting from nginx:

```
2017/06/28 13:06:51 [error] 200#0: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3007/api", host: "localhost"
```

Comment: So, you want to run a nginx in docker container ?

Comment: @JulienGuerder Yes. I've my express-API in one container and nginx serving the static content in another container.

Comment: You need to use the docker network function for connect everything together. 
Look at this link, it explain how to use docker network with example. 
http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101-host-mode/

Comment: Seems heavy. Is there a lot of conf to get this up and running?

Comment: Not really, you just have to understand how nework work

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, you want not `localhost:3007` but something like `api-upstream-server:3007` - a separate container running the app server code and exposing port 3007.

Inside the container, `localhost` is the container, not the host machine. Docker isolates the container from the host node.

But notice, you will probably have to run everything else (database, etc.) in docker containers as well.